# EWS: Can't update item body since it contains control characters (ASCII 29, 30)

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I tried to update body of an item using EWS, however, I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "The invalid value '' was specified for the 'Body' element."
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceXmlSerializationException
```

Steps to reproduce problem:

```
$item.Body.Text = 30 -as [char]
$item.Update("AlwaysOverwrite")
```

Cause of error is usage of control characters  (File, Group, Record, and Unit: FS, GS, RS and US).

Comment: Did you add/append those characters? Or were they already in the body?

Comment: Originally, they are in the body and I would like to do this: 


$item.Body.Text = 'Some string' + $item.Body.Text

This throws an error as Body already contains control characters.


However, if I try to do this (body contains characters):
$item.Body.Text = $item.Body.Text
This works!

For testing purposes, I tried to simply set body to single control character, and I get the same error:

$item.Body.Text = '(control character)'

Comment: Your second attempt may succeed because the ews client library internally says "Hey! No change, no need to submit". Would removing all the control characters be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way control characters could be removed.

Comment: No, it only throws error if I include control characters in body. I need these control characters for further processing. I can't simply omit them.

Comment: What type of body are you trying to add Text,HTML or RichText. I would say you will need to update the Extended property directly eg for HTML set the binary prop https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee217562(v=exchg.80).aspx